# Como fazer um contador de caracteres de uma textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tentei fazer um, mas sempre esbarrava em alguma limitação. Acho que minha lógica não vai dar certo, mas ainda não consegui pensar em outra.

Javascript:

```
$(document).on("keydown", "#TxtObservacoes", function () {
    var caracteresRestantes = 255;
    var caracteresDigitados = parseInt($(this).val().length);
    var caracteresRestantes = caracteresRestantes - caracteresDigitados;

    $(".caracteres").text(caracteresRestantes);
});
```

HTML:

```
<span class="caracteres">255</span> Restantes <br>
<textarea id="TxtObservacoes"></textarea>
```

Meu código: http://jsfiddle.net/5pw5L/

Comment: Ta mais quais as limitações de sua implementação? Só para entender o problema.

Comment: Se eu uso keydown o textarea ainda nao adicionou o texto digitado e a conta da errado. Se eu uso o keypress ele não detecta o backspace por exemplo. No fiddle vc podera perceber isso.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Altere o evento de keydown para input.

Veja o exemplo:

```
$(document).on("input", "#TxtObservacoes", function () {
    var limite = 255;
    var caracteresDigitados = $(this).val().length;
    var caracteresRestantes = limite - caracteresDigitados;

    $(".caracteres").text(caracteresRestantes);
});
```

Alterei também o nome de uma das variáveis, como sugestão.

O evento input cobre diversos casos de entrada de texto, como copiar e colar e manter uma tecla pressionada. Outros eventos acabam gerando a necessidade mais código, complicando o problema.

Alternativamente, se você necessitar dar suporte para versões de navegadores que não implementam o evento input, utilize o evento keyup. Você pode adicionar ambos os eventos no método **.on()** do jQuery:

```
$(document).on("input keyup", "#TxtObservacoes", function () {
...
```

Comment: O evento `input` é uma ótima opção, também funciona se um texto é colado no campo (sem uso do teclado).

Comment: Valeu @bfavaretto, usei aqui o input e ficou ótimo.

Comment: Vou alterar para recomendar somente a utilização do input, já que cobre mais casos, como o descrito pelo @bfavaretto.

Comment: Talvez seja necessário usar uma combinação de eventos, pois o `input` [pode não ser suportado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMozilla_event_reference%2Finput), dependendo do browser e da situação.

Comment: Adicionei uma observação conforme o comentário do @bfavaretto, em relação ao evento input não ser implementado em alguns navegadores.

Comment: @BernardoBotelho, é ("input keyup") sem virgula entre eles mesmo?

Comment: Sim, sem vírgula, com espaço.

Comment: @BernardoBotelho pode (deve) usar `this.value.length` em vez de `$(this).val().length`. Quanto menos jQuery melhor.

Answer (score 2):

Essa solução é simples e completa :)

http://jsfiddle.net/kyodesign/3zheoyj5/

jQuery

```
$(document).on("input", "#comentario", function() {
    var limite = 145;
    var informativo = "caracteres restantes.";
    var caracteresDigitados = $(this).val().length;
    var caracteresRestantes = limite - caracteresDigitados;

    if (caracteresRestantes <= 0) {
        var comentario = $("textarea[name=comentario]").val();
        $("textarea[name=comentario]").val(comentario.substr(0, limite));
        $(".caracteres").text("0 " + informativo);
    } else {
        $(".caracteres").text(caracteresRestantes + " " + informativo);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Este é um exemplo funcional de contagem de caracteres numa textarea.

HTML

```
<span id="cont">50</span> Restantes <br>
<textarea onkeyup="limite_textarea(this.value)" id="texto"></textarea>
```

JavaScript

```
   function limite_textarea(valor) {
    quant = 50;
    total = valor.length;
    if(total <= quant) {
        resto = quant - total;
        document.getElementById('cont').innerHTML = resto;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('texto').value = valor.substr(0,quant);
    }
}
```

**A função:**

A variável quant delimita o número máximo de caracteres a ser preenchido
Total recebe o número de caracteres já digitado no campo.
Faz verificação se o total é menor ou igual a quantidade, para ver se ainda pode ser preenchido.
Resto recebe a subtração de quant menos o total para exibir quantos caracteres ainda podem ser preenchidos.
Depois escreve no `< span id="cont">` o número de caracteres restantes.
E caso a quantidade seja maior, ele vai bloquear a digitação, ao soltar a tecla o script vai pegar todos os caracteres que forem menores do que a quantidade.

**O campo textarea:**

A única necessidade neste campo é que tenha estes dois parâmetros:
`onkeyup="limite_textarea(this.value)"` -- chama a função quando soltar uma tecla.
`id="texto"` -- id do campo - para identificação

Answer (score 0):

```
var fieldArea = document.getElementById('countCharacters');
    var msgLimit = "Limite de carácteres excedido"; 

    if (fieldArea) {
        var countCharacters = fieldArea.onkeydown = function(e){
            var fieldMaxLength = fieldArea.maxLength;
            var fieldValueLength = fieldArea.value.length;

            var result = document.getElementById('result');

            var equation = fieldMaxLength - fieldValueLength;

            //Se os carácteres digitados for menor ou igual ao maxlength
            if (fieldValueLength <= fieldMaxLength) {
                result.innerText = equation + " carácteres restantes";
            }
            //Se os carácteres digitados tiver alcançado o maxlength
            if (fieldValueLength == fieldMaxLength) {
                result.innerText = msgLimit;
            }
            console.clear();
            console.log(fieldMaxLength);
            console.log(fieldValueLength);
            console.log(equation);          
        }       

        countCharacters();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

seguindo o codigo do nosso amigo adrianoAcosta, eu também manipulei a cor vermelha quando estiver chegando ao limite de caracteres

```js
$(document).on("input", "#comentario", function() {
 var limite = 145;
    var informativo = "caracteres restantes.";
    var caracteresDigitados = $(this).val().length;
    var caracteresRestantes = limite - caracteresDigitados;

    if (caracteresRestantes <= 0) {
        var comentario = $("textarea[name=comentario]").val();
        $("textarea[name=comentario]").val(comentario.substr(0, limite));
        $(".caracteres").text("0 " + informativo);
    } else if (caracteresRestantes >= 16) {
  $( ".caracteres" ).css( "color", "#000000" );
        $(".caracteres").text(caracteresRestantes + " " + informativo); 
 } else if (caracteresRestantes >= 0 && caracteresRestantes <= 15) {
  $( ".caracteres" ).css( "color", "red" );
        $(".caracteres").text(caracteresRestantes + " " + informativo); 
 } else {
  $(".caracteres").text(caracteresRestantes + " " + informativo);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>


<p><label for="review">Seu comentário</label> <small class="caracteres"></small></p>
<textarea name="comentario" id="comentario" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: Qual é o propósito da resposta?

Comment: Essa resposta é duplicata dessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94584/137387) com conteúdo fora do escopo da pergunta adicionado. Leia [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7256/o-que-%c3%a9-o-stack-overflow) e também leia [answer].