# Textarea automático

Tags: html, css, html5

Fala, pessoal.

Eu gostaria de saber como permitir a rolagem automática do `textarea`, por exemplo, assim que o usuário vai digitando algo dentro do `textarea`, o mesmo muda de height, de acordo com o que o user digita.

Eu retirei a seta/barra de rolagem que é criada ao usuário digitar, que é criada de assim que o tamanho do texto passa da height dada ao `textarea`. Gostaria que a height do `textarea` fosse mudada automáticamente, de acordo com o texto digitado pelo usuário.

Obrigado!

Comment: Serve isso ? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25753/como-fazer-um-contador-de-caracteres-de-uma-textarea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Só uma nota HTML5 vai além das tags, então a resolução aqui não é bem esta. No caso somente com HTML e CSS não tem como fazer.

Não entendi bem o que quer dizer com seta e descer automaticamente, até aonde sei ao apertar Enter ou o texto quebrar de linha o scroll rola normalmente, talvez o que você queira é que o `textarea` aumente?

É possível usando Javascript e capturar a altura do scroll, manipulando o css em seguida, por exemplo:

```js
   function addEvent(type, el, callback)
   {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener(type, callback, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        el.attachEvent("on" + type, callback);
    } else {
        el["on" + type] = callback;
    }
   }

   function resizeTextfield(el)
   {
    var timer;

    function trigger() {
        if (!el) { return; }

        el.style.height = "auto";

        var height = el.scrollHeight;

        el.style.height = height + "px";
    }

    function exec() {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }

        timer = setTimeout(trigger, 10);
    }

    addEvent("keyup", el, exec);
    addEvent("input", el, exec);
   }

window.onload = function () {
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("increase");

    for (var i = els.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        resizeTextfield(els[i]);
    }
};
```

```css
.increase
{
    width: 480px;
    min-height: 240px; /*altura minima*/
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: none; /* pode trocar por resize: vertical; se quiser permitir redimensionar manualmente na vertical*/
}
```

```html
<textarea class="increase"></textarea>
```

Comment: Por que enquanto você está escrevendo e ultrapassa o textarea, em vez de acompanhar as palavras, as palavras se escondem e só aparecem quando você para de escrevê-las. Como posso resolver isto??

Comment: @JãoVitor eu modifiquei o código, veja se agora funciona

Comment: Toda vez que eu escrevo uma linha de textarea, parece que a height(altura) do textarea aumenta... Então toda vez que eu escrevo uma linha, o textarea aumenta, e vai ficando gigante. Como resolver isto?

Comment: @JãoVitor testei no Chrome, Firefox e IE, todos funcionaram normal, deve ser um CSS seu que está causando o problema.